# Sigar UnsatisfiedLinkError on Apache Storm topology

Tags: java, apache-storm, sigar

I am deploying a Storm topology on my machine configured as a single local cluster. I have configured the `conf/storm.yaml` to use the `storm.scheduler: "org.apache.storm.scheduler.resource.ResourceAwareScheduler"`. The topology is deployed successfully. However I am receiving an error from the `Sigar` library which says that cannot get the Process ID to use the `CPUMetric` on my topology. Here is the configuration of my topology to get metrics:

```
config.registerMetricsConsumer(LoggingMetricsConsumer.class);
Map<String, String> workerMetrics = new HashMap<String, String>();
workerMetrics.put("CPU", "org.apache.storm.metrics.sigar.CPUMetric");
config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_METRICS, workerMetrics);
```

I already copy the `sigar-1.6.4.jar` and `storm-metrics-1.2.2.jar` libraries to the `apache-storm/lib` folder. Here is the error:

```
2019-03-13 16:24:45.920 o.a.s.util Thread-10-__system-executor[-1 -1] [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getPid()J
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getPid(Native Method) ~[sigar-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.metrics.sigar.CPUMetric.<init>(CPUMetric.java:38) ~[storm-metrics-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.newInstanceImpl(Utils.java:198) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:192) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:185) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.metric.SystemBolt.registerMetrics(SystemBolt.java:150) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.metric.SystemBolt.prepare(SystemBolt.java:143) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10795$fn__10808.invoke(executor.clj:803) ~[storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__553.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native part of Sigar is not on the classpath of the worker for some reason. The native files are found inside storm-metrics.jar in the resources directory.

Why are you manually copying storm-metrics to storm/lib? The easiest way to ensure your topology dependencies are present would be making a fat jar using the maven-shade-plugin. Take a look at how storm-starter does it https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/pom.xml#L153.

I would check the log of the worker to verify that the storm-metrics.jar file is on the classpath of the worker process. The worker prints its classpath very early during boot, as does the supervisor.

You mention that you're running on a single local cluster. I'm not sure if you mean a single-node install of Storm, or if you're using LocalCluster (or equivalently the `storm local` command). If you mean you're using LocalCluster, you will need to add storm-metrics as a dependency of your topology project.

Comment: I use this command to deploy my storm job: `apache-storm-1.2.2/bin/storm jar /home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/explore-storm/target/explore-storm.jar org.sense.storm.App`. I guess it is a single node Apache Storm cluster because I did based on this: https://medium.com/real-time-streaming/setting-up-a-single-node-apache-storm-cluster-3dda02add2e9

Comment: Okay, that guide is fine and should work. I think you should check the worker log to see if storm-metrics is on the worker classpath. Alternatively you can go with a fat jar and just add storm-metrics as a dependency.

Comment: When I open the `worker.log` file the there is a line `2019-03-14 13:20:20.978 o.a.s.m.StormMetricRegistry main [INFO] Starting metrics reporters...` and also I find `storm-metrics-1.2.2.jar` there. When I build my Jar file on Eclipse IDE using `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` the log file complains because there are multiple `default.yaml` files. I also removed `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `pom.xml` file. No result achieved...

Comment: The StormMetricRegistry log line is part of storm-core, it doesn't matter. I'm not sure how Eclipse does things, but consider using Maven to build your topology instead. The reason it's complaining about multiple defaults.yaml files is that you are bundling storm-core into your jar. Make sure it has provided scope in the pom. storm-metrics should be compile scope.

Comment: Perfect. it worked. Thanks =) here is my pom.xml https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-storm/blob/master/pom.xml#L73